# What is "android.R.id.text1"?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. In the Notepad sample, I saw the following code snippet:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.noteslist_item, cursor,
        new String[] { Notes.TITLE }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
```

and in the `notelist_item.xml` file:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"   <-----------HERE
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
/>
```

So, I am wondering, what is this `android.R.id.text1`?

Also, I found `android.R.id.button1`, `button2`, `button3` in the `android.jar` file.

Are they some kind of well known IDs for some 3rd party controls?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`android.R.id.text1` is just an identifier defined in the Android framework.

In the framework, `android.R.id.text1` is an used for `TextView` views. You can find it in many layouts from the framework (`select_dialog_item`, `select_dialog_singlechoice`, `simple_dropdown_item_1line`, etc.). In Android framework xml, it is represented by `@+id/text1`.

Hence, if you use one of these layouts and want to change the text, you will need to use this id.

```
// probably in a custom ListAdapter that uses 
View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
TextView textView = (textView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
textView.setText("Oh no! not hello world again");
```

Also, you can use this same identifier to identify a `TextView` (or anything) in your custom layouts. See in the sample "Notepad", the layout file `noteslist_item.xml`.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:singleLine="true"  
/>
```

And actually, you could use `R.id.text1` as an identifier of anything else, but that would be confusing.

Comment: I have asked a related question [android.R or cutom R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082888/what-is-better-android-r-or-cutom-r)

Comment: I have a somewhat related question, is it possible to do something like `R.id.Interger.parseInt("someID");`? I haven't seen a way that you can do it using R.id, but is there a similar way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

It's a build-in layout (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`) view id used for default lists etc.

Answer (score 4):

android.R.id.text1 is a TextView in layout (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
you can see this in

(path to ur Android SDK)\platforms\android-\data\res\layout

folder

Answer (score 2):

android.R.id.text1 is the id of the TextView defined in the android's predefined layout **android.layout.simple_list_item1**. so it is just like give an id which is already described rather than giving a new id.

Comment: And I am very curious to know if it is [a good practice to reuse framework id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082888/what-is-better-android-r-or-cutom-r)

Answer (score 1):

android.R.id.text1 is the id of TextView which is defined in notelist_item.xml.
You can find and use the widget by its id.

Comment: +1 because it is actually correct in the context of this question, although incomplete

Answer (score 1):

The text1 part (and the other buttons) are the reference for your java code  to the textView defined in your layout.xml.  the rest of that Android.R.id tells the code to find an Android resource with an Id of 'text1' for example.

Answer (score 0):

android.R.id.Text1 is a actually id of **simple_dropdown_item_1line** in the android 
if you click on **simple_dropdown_item_1line** with **ctrl+touchpad**(if you use laptop) you see the there is a id of simple_dropdown_item_1line you use the same text1 in your **xmlfile** give your styles in your xmlfile then you will run it easily