# What is better android.R or custom R?

Tags: android, coding-style, convention

When I started developping android applications, I had a tendency to define custom R values wherever I need, in particular in layout files. For instance:

```
findViewById(R.id.customerName).setText(customer.getName())
```

with layout:

```
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@id/customerName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Now I realize, it might be better to use `android.R` instead.

```
findViewById(android.R.id.text1).setText(customer.getName())
```

with layout:

```
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

What practice do you follow? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: Custom too... I think it is better to have your own stuff used rather than the native OS. Which you don't control in any way

Comment: I don't get that. What kind of control do I gain when I use custom identifiers?

Comment: `android:id="@android:id/customerName"` - is this correct? as it is written `customerName` seems to be a id defined at the top level of the Android SDk, but it isn't;  you wanted to say maybe `android:id="@+id/customerName`??

Comment: @Paul. Absolutely right. Wrong copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no big advantage or disadvantage of the framework id *vs* the custom id in layouts.

Advantages of using framework identifiers:

- Avoid the creation of more identifiers. Saves one field in the apk (and there is an apk size limit).
- Must be used in some situations, like `ListActivity`

Drawbacks of using framework identifiers:

- Don't provide a descriptive name

In both practices

- The code will work in the future
- Missing references are discovered at runtime, and hidden at compile time

I thought the the samples in the SDK would help me take a decision, and (guess what?) it doesn't. The Notepad and LunarLander applications use the `android.R.id` for the view identifiers, whereas the ApiDemos project uses custom identifiers.

Best practice for GestureBuilder which mixes both approaches? (`@+id/addButton` and `@android:id/empty`)

IHMO, worse practice for HelloActivity and JetBoy which define `@+id/text` `@+id/Button01`... This is not descriptive and could have been replaced by (`@andoid:id/button1`, or by `@+id/startButton`)

Answer (score 17):

`android.R` is meant for utilizing resources built in to the operating system.

There are many images/layouts/etc... that come with the operating system that you can just reference using `android.R`

if you are referencing your own resources that you have created, *most* always use `R.` and in most situations I recommend trying to stay away from the built in resources as they change version to version.

Comment: Well, if you want to use the [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), then your own layout that you have created must define a `@android:id/list`. This contradicts the "always use `R.`for your own resources".

Comment: Also, I don't believe framework resources change from version to version. That would break *everything*

Comment: in fact they do, the built in animated progress indicator for example, visually changes *every* primary release...

Answer (score 1):

Custom. The system-provided IDs come with a risk of referring, in code, to a resource that is not present in the project. Customs IDs exist iff there's a corresponding resource - a drawable, a view, a layout or what have you.

Comment: And yet, if your custom resource (say `R.id.customerName`) is defined in your project in a different layout, the `findViewById()` will fail exactly likewise. I suppose you're not expected to have a working application simply because it compiles. This is inherent to the separation of code and XML. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, the basic correctness of project is still kinda required :) I never said using custom IDs will protect you from *all* possible errors. Just from one specific class of errors - where you're trying to load android.R.layout.foo, and it's not quite there. Also, what jondavidjohn said about system provided resources (not just IDs).

Comment: Do you reuse several time a resource in your project, or do you define a resource only for a layout? For instance, if you have two layouts _main screen_ and _customer details_, will you define `@+id/CustomerNameTextView` in both OR will you define `@+id/mainScreenCustomerNameTV` and  `@+id/customerDetailsCustomerNameTV`?

Comment: You mean IDs of views on layouts? I do, occasionally. But those are still my custom IDs. Why?

Comment: Because if you reuse `@+id/CustomerNameTextView` in several layouts, you have exactly the same problem than using `android.R.id.text`: `findViewById()`can throw a view not found exception.

Comment: I never said using custom IDs will protect you from all possible errors.

Answer (score -1):

You need your own R.java class as it contains references to all of your resources (layouts, images, strings, etc.)

If you want to get a reference to a View with id of "myView", you would use R.id.myView.
If you want to get a reference to built-in Android resources, you would use android.R.id.text

Take a look at the following page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: I have completed my question because you have missed the point.