# R.string doesn't show up strings I manually defined in res/values/strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I added some `string`s to the strings.xml file, as the following:

```
<string name="29">Beaf Stake"</string>
```

I know that this is the way to retrieve `string`s from the ressources:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.29);
```

But the problem is that I don't find this `string` listed in `R.string`. I imported my Project's `R` as following:

```
import xxxx.xx.xxxx.xxx.R;
```

I tried restarting Eclipse with no luck, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a numeric variable name is wrong . It won't allow such thing and instead throw an error.

I request you to change your string name. May be follow the recommendations [Are there conventions on how to name resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165582/are-there-conventions-on-how-to-name-resources)

Comment: Yes you were right! I changed the string name to something other than numeric and I works. I would accept the answer as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Your resource name can't start with a number and 
 you have to escape quotes either with an esacape character or enclose the whole sting.

```
<string name="29">Beaf Stake"</string>
```

should be

```
<string name="29">"Beaf Stake"</string>
```

or

```
<string name="29">Beaf Stake/"</string>
```

[Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)