# How to set android:src="@android:drawable/presence_busy" programatically for imagebuton

Tags: android, user-interface

When I use ImageButton I am able to chose android:src="@android:drawable/presence_busy" as image for my imagebutton by choosing "presence_bussy" on System tab of Resource dialog box but I do not know how to do this programatically. i.e. if my ImageButton is btn11 I am using

```
btn11.setImageResource(R.xxxxxx.xxxxx);
```

what should I use here for setImageResuorce ?!

Comment: use this   `btn11.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.presence_busy)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it as:

```
btn11.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_busy);
```

Comment: Depending on your imports, but you should probably do android.R.drawable.presence_busy

Comment: @FunkTheMonk are you sure? I though that android.R is meant for utilizing resources built in to the operating system. As said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082888/what-is-better-android-r-or-custom-r

Comment: use R.drawable.presence_busy

Comment: @khubaib wrong op wants to use drawable in android.R.drawable package

Comment: @android:drawable/presence_busy is such a resource, although you will get the version of the drawable as determined by the device you're running on (so it may appear different across different android versions / vendors)

Comment: @Raghunandan yeah thanks, I just saw setting "drawable resource" and didn't read the question were carefully.

Comment: @Raghunandan what are you trying to say?

Comment: @khubaib what i meant is op wants to use a drawable resource in android.R.drawable check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html if you don't understand