# Custom AlertDialog list layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have been working with custom AlertDialog selections for the last few days and stumbled upon **android.R.layout**.xxx layouts.

A good example would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304608/what-is-android-r-id-text1) question. The android documentation is extremely [skimpy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html) on this...

What I haven't found though is just how to look up components of such layouts. I tried to open these layouts in Eclipse, but it says it can't and I haven't been able to find a site that would list these layouts.

So how do I find out what **android.R.id**'s are in such a layout and what layout is good for what usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the list of layout files here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout

Open up the file you're interested in to check which IDs are in each

Comment: Not fully what I hoped for, but it's good to know this isn't exactly a documented feature. Thanks

Comment: @velis - It's not documented at all, unfortunately. So, for now, this is the best option.