# Using ListView or TextView with the ArrayAdapter on Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm trying to print an Array String[] in the listView of my fragment and I always get an error. Here's my fragment class:

```
public class Fragment_Database extends Fragment

public Fragment_Database() {
    // Constructor
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_database, container, false);

    ListView list;
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String[] names = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", "Suse",
            "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone"};

    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_database, names));
    return v;
}
```

}

Here's the XML:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView" />
```

If I put a ListView in the XML I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

And if I put a TextView in the XML, I get this one:

> android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is wrong.

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_database, names));
```

you use this code.

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
```

R.layout.fragment_database is not ListviewItem's xml file.
You use custom item layout or simpleItemLayout.
read this page and try again.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thanks! :D It works... Which layout should i use if I want a gridView instead of a simplee_list... ? do you know? i'm closing the question after :P

Comment: I'm not use GridView. but i can this page easily. [link]http://androidexample.com/Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=75&aaid=99

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_database, names));
```

Try

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Regarding the details of `android.R.id.text1` found  [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304608/what-is-android-r-id-text1)

Comment: When I should use android.R or simply R? What is the difference...  Because I've seen both over the internet..

Comment: because your ArrayAdapter<String> expecting the underlying textView. which could not found in your case. Regarding details please see the mentioned link.