# How is android.R.id.text1 being used in this tutorial without a widget in the layout with the same ID?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I'm following along with [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html#exercise-using-retrofit-to-query-stackoverflow-in-android) to build a sample android app using Retrofit and the StackOverflow API. In their MainActivity code on the onClick(View v) method they are referencing the view `android.R.id.text1` but I do not see anything in their layout files with the ID of "text1". How can this be?

Also, I'm used to using OnClickListener as an anonymous inner-class. In this example the entire MainActivity implements OnClickListener and `onClick(View)` is overridden in the class itself. Is there any benefit to doing it this way? They're using a switch statement to determine which layout item is being clicked and putting all the actions in the single `onClick(View)` method.

Thanks!

Comment: `android.R.id.text1` is the built-in `TextView`'s id in android. In your following example, they used built-in layout `simple_list_item 1.xml` ,
you can see [full file with its id here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304608/what-is-android-r-id-text1), android.R.id.text1 is an identifier for a `TextView`.

As for your second question, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082892/best-way-to-implement-view-onclicklistener-in-android) seems to have the answer.

**Bonus**: Checkout [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to handle user interactions. Give it a try!