# Converting string containing id to an id type Int

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a string that contains an id for a button:

```
val stringContainingId = "R.id.testBtn"
```

And I testBtn is set as id in activity_main:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/testBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

So, I want to set the text of this button in my MainActivity. stringContainingId is a string, so I have to convert to id with type Int:

```
val id: Int = applicationContext.resources.getIdentifier("R.id.testBtn", "id", applicationContext.packageName)
```

Then changing the text of testBtn:

```
        val testBtn = findViewById<Button>(id)
        testBtn.text = "Other text"
```

But at runtime app crashes, and shows this error:

```
testBtn must not be null
```

But if changed to `findViewById<Button>(R.id.testBtn)`, eveything goes smoothly.

What's wrong with variable 'id' that is getting the id from string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Android Java framework, android.R.id.testBtn is an identifier of a Button . You can find it in many layouts from the framework (select_dialog_item, select_dialog_singlechoice, simple_dropdown_item_1line, etc.). In Android framework xml, it is represented by @+id/testBtn

Mate, you get id = 0 cause by `R.id.testBtn` not a String. It actually an `int` variable. If you want to get identifier, you just need add `testBtn` to find it.

```
val id: Int = applicationContext.resources.getIdentifier(testBtn, "id", applicationContext.packageName)
```

Read more in document official android and I believe you know more than.

e.g: https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.content.res.Resources/getIdentifier

[What is "android.R.id.text1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304608/what-is-android-r-id-text1)

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/R.id

Answer (score 0):

Use just `“testBtn”`, not `“R.id.testBtn”` in `getIdentifier()`.